# OnMouseEnter не всегда срабатывает C# forms

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse-event, мышь

Написал код с ивентом `OnMouseEnter`, он работает, но если начать резко дёргать мышью вокруг кнопок, то он будет работать только в некоторых случаях. Смотрел лаунчер на Delphi, там таких проблем нет. На форумах пишут про то, что это проблема винды (курсор скачет по промежуткам, а не плавно), но на других языках как-то же работает.

Вот кусок кода от кастомной кнопки:

```cs
protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);

    eventAnimation.ChangeTransparancy(this, 50, 255, 255, 255, Color.Black);
    MouseEntered = true;
    Invalidate(); 
}

protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseLeave(e);

    eventAnimation.ChangeTransparancy(this, 255, 0, 0, 0, Color.White);
    MouseEntered = false;
    Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Ну вы сами ответили на свой вопрос.

Comment: @aepot в каком смысле, у меня это работает не всегда, на других языках нормально.

Comment: На других языках, может, заморочились с тем, чтобы интерполировать движение мыши между отдельными MouseMove и обнаруживать, когда она должна была пройти через нужный прямоугольник на предыдущем перемещении. Вряд ли это само собой заработает, если дело в Windows.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ну так что-то можно с этим сделать? Есть идеи, как в коде показать?

Comment: [Оно](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5247322/Mouse-Smoothing)?

Comment: @aepot гляну, там много. спасибо